# How I search and print matched wold in UNIX or perl?

Tags: perl, unix

```
1=ABC,2=mnz,3=xyz
1=pqr,3=ijk,2=lmn
```

I have this in text file I want to search `1=` and that should print only matched word `1=ABC` and `1=pqr`

Any suggestions in Perl or Unix?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

**Input:**

```
$ cat grep.in 
1=ABC,2=mnz,3=xyz
1=pqr,3=ijk,2=lmn
4=pqr,3=ijk,2=lmn
```

**Command:**

```
$ grep -o '1=[^,]\+' grep.in 
1=ABC
1=pqr
```

**Explanations:**

You can just use `grep` on your input

- `-o` is to output only the matching pattern
- `1=[^,]\+` the regex will match strings that start by `1=` followed by at least one character that is not a comma (I have based this on the hypothesis that there is no comma in the right part of the `=` except the separator)
- if you want to accept empty result you can change the `\+` by `*`

Comment: Thank you..Any suggestions how can I try for multiple pattern ? I tried using egrep but didn't worked . Ex: grep for 1= and 2=

Comment: @user4786572:
if you want `1` and `2`, then replace `grep -o '1=[^,]\+'` by `grep -o '[12]=[^,]\+'`
Let me know if you have any question!

Comment: Sorry Allan..I have something starts with 1 , 11 and 38 to search how I use this ? 1=xyz,11=pqr,38=lmn

Comment: @user4786572: just use `grep -oE '(1|11|38)=[^,]+' grep.in` this should work fine.

Comment: Thank you that worked  ..One last how I print the output in same line not one below one..I want to print as  1=xyz 11=mno 38=pqr

Comment: @user4786572: after the command just add `| tr '\n' ' '` to transform all the EOL char into spaces and have everything on one single line This gives you the command `grep -oE '(1|11|38)=[^,]+' grep.in | tr '\n' ' '`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your input data is in CSV format. Here is a Perl solution based on [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV)

- parse the CSV content row-wise
- print out columns that start with `1=`

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    binary   => 1,
    eol      => "\n",
}) or die "CSV\n";

# parse
while (my $row = $csv->getline(\*DATA)) {
    foreach (@{ $row }) {
        print "$_\n" if /^1=/;
    }
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
1=ABC,2=mnz,3=xyz
1=pqr,3=ijk,2=lmn
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
1=ABC
1=pqr
```

Replace `DATA` with `STDIN` to read the input from standard input instead.

Comment: Honestly, for simple CSV like this, I'd call `Text::CSV` overkill, and split more than sufficient.